# Save received pictures in Gmail in my Google Photos, I cannot do it in anyway

Tags: gmail

Tried everything to save my received pictures in Gmail to my Google Photos but nothing works. Help.

Comment: i found the answer! jippie!

Comment: Go to photos.google.com
Click on the Menu button located at the top-left corner (3 horizontal bars) > Settings.
Enable Show Google Drive photos & videos in your Photos library option:
 look just under the middle on page: https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-enable-google-photos-folder-in-your-google-drive/

Comment: Luca, can you post that as an answer to your question, please.

Answer (score 3):

**From the comment above:**

1. Go to https://photos.google.com.
2. Click on the Menu button located at the top-left corner (3 horizontal bars) > Settings.
3. Enable Show Google Drive photos & videos in your Photos library option:

Reference: https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-enable-google-photos-folder-in-your-google-drive/

Comment: This only synced google drive images to google photos. It didn't showed gmail attachments. I had to first add gmail attachment to drive one by one. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: It is not working anymore, all the photos are downloaded in .json format

Comment: Sorry @MarioRossi.  I was only relaying this answer from the comment that the original poster had added to their question.  I don't know how else to help you.